# how can I svn commit from my php

Tags: php, svn

I have been trying to get my php to be able to create sql procedure files. My page does everything just as it needs to. It even writes to file correctly, but now I need it to add the file to svn and then also commit. I have been trying

```
system("svn commit", $trash);
```

but I cannot seem to get it to work. I have been able to get

```
system("svn add ".$fileName);
```

to work and i get common "A................fileName added" or what ever it says. I think that when I try to commit the file svn is waiting for authentication or something, I think this because I don't get anything back in the `$trash`...

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You might don't want to use `exec` or `system` and use [an SVN module instead](http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with a full svn commit command line like :

```
svn commit --username USER --password PASS
```

Further options available at : http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re06.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a PECL extension for working with SVN:

- [`svn_commit` — Sends changes from the local working copy to the repository](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.svn-commit.php)

Example from Manual:

```
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_USERNAME, 'Bob');
svn_auth_set_parameter(SVN_AUTH_PARAM_DEFAULT_PASSWORD, 'abc123');
var_dump(svn_commit('Log message of Bob\'s commit', array(realpath('calculator'))));
```

---

There is also a PEAR package:

- http://pear.php.net/package/VersionControl_SVN

> VersionControl_SVN is a simple OO-style interface for Subversion, the free/open-source version control system. VersionControl_SVN can be used to manage trees of source code, text files, image files -- just about any collection of files.

Comment: if i understand right. doesnt this require to be compiled with the php? to be able to use these methods?

Comment: @kyle it's merely a matter of doing `pecl install`. The PEAR package can be installed with `pear install`

Comment: I do not have access to be able to do this. the svn and php are all on another server that i dont have access to except to check in my own code... can i still do this?

Comment: @kyle in that case, go with the PEAR package. Download it and all the dependencies and put them in your project folder. Then upload it with your other files.